# Community Theme Full width layout

Tags: community, lightning-design-system

we use the napili theme which has a width of 1140px. 
For a specific page i created a new community layout with the following code:

```
<aura:attribute name="column1" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="contentPanel">
        {!v.column1}
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following css

```
.THIS .contentPanel:before,
.THIS .contentPanel:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.THIS .contentPanel {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But through this layout will be inserted into

```
<div class="cCenterPanel" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-by="247:0">
```

which has max-width:1140px it is not possible to get this page full width over the whole desktop.

Does anyone have an idea, how to override this max-width for that special page?

Comment: I hope someone will find this post useful. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162103/how-to-set-the-page-layout-using-css-conditionally-napili-template-salesforce

Answer (score 3):

figured it out..

every page have its own body-class

```
.comm-page-custom-PAGENAME .cCenterPanel {
    max-width:100% !important;       
    margin:0
}
```

add this to your community css